# Hibernate validation with custom messages in property file

Tags: spring, bean-validation, jersey-2.0, hibernate-validator

Hi am using hibernate validator in jersey rest service.
Here how can we pass value to the property file message as follows

```
empty.check= Please enter {0}
```

here in {0} i need to pass the value from annotation

```
@EmptyCheck(message = "{empty.check}") private String userName
```

here in the {0} i need to pass "user name", similarly i need to reuse message

please help me out to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by altering your annotation to provide a field description and then exposing this in the validator.

First, add a `description` field to your annotation:

```
@Target({ FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = EmptyCheckValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface EmptyCheck {
    String description() default "";
    String message() default "{empty.check}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Next, change your message so that it uses a named parameter; this is more readable.

```
empty.check= Please enter ${description}
```

Since you're using hibernate-validator, you can get the hibernate validator context within your validation class and add a context variable.

```
public class EmptyCheckValidator 
             implements ConstraintValidator<EmptyCheck, String> {
    String description;
    public final void initialize(final EmptyCheck annotation) {
        this.description = annotation.description();
    }

    public final boolean isValid(final String value, 
                                 final ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if(null != value && !value.isEmpty) {
            return true;
        }
        HibernateConstraintValidatorContext ctx = 
            context.unwrap(HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class);
        ctx.addExpressionVariable("description", this.description);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Finally, add the description to the field:

```
@EmptyCheck(description = "a user name") private String userName
```

This should produce the following error when userName is null or empty:

```
Please enter a user name
```

Comment: @ beerbajay Thanks for replay. But if multiple parameter are there in the message like empty.check= Please enter {0} {1}. How can we achieve..?

Comment: @ShashiDk You call `addExpressionVariable` several times with the different variable names. From where are you getting these parameters?